# Disable button with Javascript depending on PHP value?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, virtuemart

I'd like to disable an "Add To Cart" button on my form if certain conditions are met.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Sequence Number</th>
<th>Expiry Date</th>
<th>Add To Cart</th>
</tr>

<?php
foreach ( $this->products as $product ) {

    // Show the horizontal seperator
    if ($iBrowseCol == 1 && $iBrowseProduct > $BrowseProducts_per_row) { ?>
    <div class="horizontal-separator"></div>
    <?php }
?>

<tr>
<td id="sequencenumber">//php code which retrieves custom Sequence Number from the database</td>
<td id="expirydate">//php code which retrieves Expiry Dates from the database</td>
<td><span class="addtocartbutton"><input type="submit" id="addtocartbtn" />
</span></td>
</tr>

<?php } } ?>
</table>
```

Each item has its own "Sequence Number" as well as "Expiry Date". Here's the catch: Two products can have the same "Sequence Number"; however ALL products have different "Expiry Dates".

I would like the "addtocartbtn" to be disabled for the product with the later Expiry Date.

I had something like this in mind (this will be included in the "foreach" php function for each product; or that is what the goal is):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($sequencenumber.is($sequencenumber) && $("#expirydate") <= $("#expirydate"))
   {
   $("#addtocartbtn").disabled == false;
   }
else {
   $("#addtocartbtn").disabled == true;
}   
);
});

</script>
```

The part I'm struggling with is getting it to work for each product. So it must only disable the addtocartbutton for the product **IF** the Sequence Number is the same AND if the Expiry Date is later than the other product with the same Sequence Number.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and hide it?

```
if ($sequencenumber.is($sequencenumber) && $("#expirydate") <= $("#expirydate"))
   {
   $("#addtocartbtn").disabled == false;
   }
else {
   $("#addtocartbtn").css("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: This one is working thanks a lot. However, it hides the button for all the products which are loaded. So currently, it sees that two sequence numbers are the same and then hides the button for all the loaded products.

Comment: I would suggest then to iterate through each product in a for loop and nesting the if statement in there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `.prop`
Something like this

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  if ($sequencenumber.is($sequencenumber) && $("#expirydate") <= 
 $("#expirydate"))
 {
 $("#addtocartbtn").prop('disabled',false);
 }
 else {
 $("#addtocartbtn").prop('disabled',true);
 }   
 );
 });
</script>
```

for more lesson about `.prop` you may refer to [this](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)